# Push object into local array from asynchronous callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis

I use node.js on my server and I use redis key-store for storing data about my characters. Every connection has it own character. I want to get all data about characters(Person, has its name, age, profession, ...) into Characters array, so I can then selectively send it to connected clients.

```
var Characters = [];
for (var ID in Connections) {
    redis_client.HGETALL(ID, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            Characters.push(result);
        }
    });
}
console.log(Characters);
```

I have read, that this is due to asynchronous vs synchronous problem, so I made global variable character.

```
//global variables
var character;
//function code
var Characters = [];
for (var ID in Connections) {
    redis_client.HGETALL(ID, function(err, result) {
        character = result;
    });
    if(character) {
         console.log(character); // returns correct result
         // make copy of character
        Characters.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(character)));
        character = undefined;
    }
}
console.log(Characters); // array of 1 character * number of connection
                                                    //BUT I expect different character for each connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different ways,

the easiest way would be creating calling the async function one after another, as follows

```
    var Characters = [];
    var objectKeys = Object.keys(Connections);
    var ID = 0; 
    if (ID < objectKeys.length) 
        doCall(objectKeys[ID]);
    else 
        console.log(Characters);
   function doCall(key) {

        redis_client.HGETALL(key, function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                Characters.push(result);
            }
            ID++;
            if ( ID < objectKeys.length)
               doCall(objectKeys[ID]);
            else 
               console.log(Characters);
        });
   }
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain me why if I replace console.log(Characters); at the 3rd row from th end with for (var ID in Connections) { Connections[ID].emit("snapshot", { MyIndex: Indices[ID], Characters: Characters });} (its socketio sending function) then whole code doesn't work(even on line where is ID++; - ID is undefined and turns into NaN. BUT: If i put this for cycle into another function and only call this function instead of console.log(Characters); code works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Regular for loop doesn't work correctly when you have async call and global variables.  Here is a loop version that would work (make sure async is installed. if not do "npm install async"):

```
var async = require('async');   
var Characters = [];

async.each(Connections, function(ID, callback) {
  redis_client.HGETALL(ID, function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        Characters.push(result);
    }
    callback(null);
  });
}, function(err) { // this function gets called when the loop is done
  console.log("finish:");
   // print out your array
  for (var i = 0, len = Characters.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(Characters[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: async.each wont interate through Connection array.
I have:  for (ID in Connections) {console.log(ID);} and this prints keys to objects in Connections. And under this command I have async.each(Connections, ... But it wont do any operation, even when previous "for" prints  some keys, it will just print "finish".

Comment: async.each() should.  Did you call callback(null) as in the answer?  without that, async.each() won't continue to process the next item in the array

Comment: Here is the example I ran and it works as expected, just not using HGETALL():     var async = require('async');
    var Characters = [];
    var Connections = [1, 2, 3];

    async.each(Connections, function(ID, callback) {
        Characters.push(ID);
        callback(null);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("finish: %d", Characters.length);
      for (var i = 0, len = Characters.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(Characters[i]);
      }
    });